# Testing a VSCode extension that involves opening a folder/workspace

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VSCode extension that takes the path of the file currently opened in the workspace into account.

So to have a reproducible test, I'm trying to open the test folder itself in VSCode and then open the test file in it, like this:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";

test("whatever", async function() {
    let workspaceUri = vscode.Uri.file(__dirname);
    // the tests stop here...
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder", workspaceUri);
    await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(__filename);
})
```

Problem is when I do that, as probably referred to [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58#issuecomment-205370778), the tests just stop running before I actually test my code.

Is there a way I can safely open a workspace and use it during tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the **docs** for testing extensions:
[Testing-extensions-docs](https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/testing-extensions/)

In the **.vscode/launch.json** file of your extension in development, you can **pass arguments** like so (from the docs):

```
"args": ["file or folder name", "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}", "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceRoot}/out/test" ]
```

So you could create a **testing directory-structure** with all the files that you care  for in that folder you specify in the config and add those directories/files to your **.vscodeignore** (the default test-directory is in there already).

the **alternative** that i have been using so far is using a **bash script** with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $0 = command itself
# $1 = extension-directory(relative path)
# $2 = process-id of code to kill

[ -z "$1" ] && { echo "path-argument not supplied"; exit 1; }
[ -z "$2" ] || { xkill -id $2; }

cd $1
vsce package
file=$(find . -name "*.vsix")
code --install-extension $file
code &
echo $!
```

All that remains is opening a folder in the launched code-instance and executing any commands in question.
Setting up an appropriate testing-environment seems more profitable to me in the longterm, at least when it can be predicted that many tests will have to be made.

Comment: Thanks @ancient child for the answer. The method basically works but not consistently. For example, using `${workspaceFolder}` doesn't work and just launches the extension development host with no folder opened. Some absolute paths work, but these are not helpful for me because I can't guarantee any absolute paths on the test system. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @MadeOfAir I'm trying to do that, but I can't. My test always start on an empty workspace. Did it still working on the latest vscode version?

Comment: the new doc link for this is `https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension`, it does not mention this folder argument but it still works (v1.53)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not work for me in 2023. I could not get VS Code to open a workspace through modifying the `launch.json`.

Instead, [@vscode/test-electron runTests](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-test/blob/a2cf86042579392c151a5632c63d03372a018401/lib/runTest.ts) takes a `launchArgs` argument. If the first argument is a directory this will be opened as workspace.

```js
await runTests({extensionDevelopmentPath, 
                extensionTestsPath, 
                launchArgs:[path_to_directory] 
               });
```

For testing, I set this to a temporary directory created by [tmp-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp-promise). My `runTests.ts` is:

```js
import * as path from "path";
import { runTests } from "@vscode/test-electron";
import { file, dir } from 'tmp-promise';

async function main() {
  try {
    const extensionDevelopmentPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../");
    const extensionTestsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./suite/index");

    const {path:tempdir, cleanup} = await dir({unsafeCleanup:true});
    await runTests({extensionDevelopmentPath, 
                    extensionTestsPath, 
                    launchArgs:[tempdir] });
    cleanup();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to run tests");
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

main();
```

The [sample in the VS Code test repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-test/blob/main/sample/test/runTest.ts) is good place to look to get a good, presumably up-to-date, example to work from.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ***VSBrowser.instance.openResources(path)*** to open a workspace/folder in VSCode instance;

```
import { WebDriver, VSBrowser } from 'vscode-extension-tester';
import path = require('path');
...

suite('Sample Test suite XYZ', () => {
    const test_project_path = path.join(__dirname, "path", "to", "prj");
    
    setup(async () => {
        driver = VSBrowser.instance.driver;
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000);
    });

    test("Open a workspace in VSCode instance", async () => {
        await VSBrowser.instance.openResources(path.resolve(test_project_path));
    });

});

...
```

Comment: This is answer is incomplete. VSBrowser comes from the [vscode-extension-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-extension-tester) package, which executes integration tests in a much different way. This is not available in the default integration tests provided by the yeoman template.