# VSCode Extension Integration Testing: Opening of folder in the test stops the test run

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing integration tests in which I have to clone a repo and open the folder using `vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.openFolder', uri);` in test window and then run tests against it. But as soon as the folder opens up, the test stops.
There are already few questions on stackoverflow, but none of them presents an answer.

[Testing a VSCode extension that involves opening a folder/workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456193/testing-a-vscode-extension-that-involves-opening-a-folder-workspace/63830094#63830094)

[VSCode: Tests won't proceed after using executeCommand to open a sample project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889998/vscode-tests-wont-proceed-after-using-executecommand-to-open-a-sample-project)

I don't want to use Cypress Library.

Comment: Just because the linked question had no answer at the time of writing this one there's no reason to ask basically the same question again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing a VSCode extension that involves opening a folder/workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456193/testing-a-vscode-extension-that-involves-opening-a-folder-workspace)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I tried to reach out to the author of the linked question as it was asked a year ago, by writing another answer there as I didn't have reputation > 50. So the mod told me to open a new question and my answer was deleted.